# Why am I getting NullPointer Exception in this Android project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner in FireBase database. I wrote this code for retrieving user data after authentication. The authentication part is working well but the data retrieving part is crashing my app with this error.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
>
> at com.kcw.firebasebasics.UserInterface$1.onDataChange(UserInterface.java:58)
>   at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:75)
>   at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:63)
>   at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:55)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

Here is the code that I wrote and I wrote a comment on line 58 (the line causing error) to identify it.

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
DatabaseReference reference;
TextView greeting;
String name,text;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_interface);
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() 
                                .child(firebaseUser.getUid());
    greeting = findViewById(R.id.greet_msg);

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String text = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();//line 58

            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(text);
                name = object.getString("username");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String message = "WELCOME ";
            message = message + name.toUpperCase();
            greeting.setText(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Help me resolve this.

I verified whether there is any null object in my database and I didn't find any.

I also tried making all my String variables global but that didn't work either

And finally a picture of my database after registering users.

[link to database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0krnw.png)

Comment: Hi there. Won't you have to call `.child("users")` before `.child(firebaseUser.getUid())` on the `DatabaseReference` object?

Comment: Yeah I just realized and fixed it. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong path in the database `reference`, it should be under `users` node :

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() 
    .child("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
greeting = findViewById(R.id.greet_msg);

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exist()) {
          String text = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();//line 58

          try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(text);
            name = object.getString("username");
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          String message = "WELCOME ";
          message = message + name.toUpperCase();
          greeting.setText(message);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation, [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()) returns null when there is no data at the location you queried.  You should check if data actually [exists()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#exists()) there before calling getValue(), or at least manually check for null before calling toString().